# Get coordinate value displayed at the buttom of qgis window with pyqgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, coordinates

Does anyone know how I can get the coordinate value displayed at the buttom of the qgis window? I have been searching through the qgis api but am not able to find anything suitable..

Comment: seems to me this question has been asked 1000 times ... "clicked coordinates qgis python" in google led me to several answers of **gis.stack exchange** ...

Answer (score 3):

this code is a simple example for access to cursor coordinates:

```
def canvasMoveEvent(event):
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()
    point = canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
    print ('({:.4f}, {:.4f})'.format(point[0], point[1]))

from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint

canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 
pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)

pointTool.canvasMoveEvent = canvasMoveEvent

canvas.setMapTool( pointTool )
```

I hope it helps you